# preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 14 after i upgraded to php7

Tags: php, mysql

Please, i need help to resolve this issue. i am getting this warning after i upgraded my server to php7.

```
} elseif (strlen($phrase) == stripos($phrase, '*') + 1) {
                $phrase = str_replace('*', '', $phrase);
                $collapsed_phrase = explode(' ', $phrase);
                if (count($collapsed_phrase) > 1) {
                    $pattern = '/\b(' . $phrase . '[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/i';
                    $res = preg_match_all($pattern, $data['adtitle'], $mass);
            }
```

I error stack is pointing to the above block.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line generates this error?

Comment: Hi there, please add your output error here as well. It will help us identify the problem quicker.

Comment: you should add your $phrase + error output here

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the input in `$phrase` contains special characters. To make sure custom input is not causing this, always use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) when inserting input into regular expressions.